# How to move over from init.d to upstart for nginx

Tags: upstart, init.d, nginx, mongodb

I have an init.d script for nginx that normally works fine. However, after a reboot it doesn't work properly and the worker process would die leaving just the master process.

nginx has some mongodb stuff (nginx-gridfs) compiled in and needs to start after mongodb which is being started by upstart.

That's all I've been able to figure out after some troubleshooting. I believe I have to change over nginx to upstart and make it dependent on mongo. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nginx-gridfs connects to mongodb, the db server should already be running and ready. This was causing a problem.
First I removed the /etc/init.d/nginx script using 'update-rc.d remove nginx' 
Then I created an 'upstart' script in /etc/init/nginx.conf :

```
# nginx

description "nginx http daemon"

#start on mongodb  
start on (local-filesystems
    and net-device-up IFACE=lo
    and started mongodb) 
stop on stopped mongodb

env DAEMON=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx 
env PID=/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid

expect fork 
respawn 
respawn limit 10 5

pre-start script
        $DAEMON -t
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                then exit $?
        fi
        # Add a sleep of 10 sec. to allow mongodb to finish starting up
        sleep 10 
end script

exec $DAEMON
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Try to kill nginx. Respawn will never happen. And `sudo start nginx` says: `start: Job is already running: nginx`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't set it up correctly use `update-rc.d <yourscript> start [startorder] 2 3 4 5 . stop [end order] 0 1 6 .` to create the runlevel links.

If your script is done correctly, it accepts `start` and `stop` command, check that all dependencies are started before your script, normally 40 is safe for *startorder*, and that all services that depend of your script end before it, 20 is probably good enough for *endorder*.

To better know how to make a good script take a look to the ones in your `/etc/init.d`

Comment: Edited my question to clarify. I believe I did use update-rc.d properly. Anyway, figured out how to set up the 'upstart' script.